# How to create an Array for Tuples in Scala?

Tags: arrays, scala, object, functional-programming, scala.js

Im trying to create an empty Array to store coordinates of an object in an Tuple which is then stored in an Array.

When I try:

```
var walls = Array[Tuple2]()
```

Im getting this error message:

```
kinds of the type arguments (Tuple2) do not conform to the expected kinds of the type parameters (type T).
[error] Tuple2's type parameters do not match type T's expected parameters:
[error] class Tuple2 has two type parameters, but type T has none
[error]         var walls = Array[Tuple2]()
```

Is there any possibility to do this?

Comment: You want something like `Array.empty[(Int, Int)]` or whatever type your coordinates will have. - also, you probably want to remove the two layers of mutability as well as avoid using `Arrays`

Answer (score 4):

`Tuple2` is a type constructor (of kind `[*, *] => *`).

`Array` is a type constructor too (of kind `[*] => *`).

You have to apply `Tuple2` to two types (of kind `*`) in order to make it suitable as an argument of `Array`.

That's why `Array[(Int, Int)]` aka `Array[Tuple2[Int, Int]]` is working while `Array[Tuple2]` is not.

Answer (score 2):

Okay I found a way:

```
var walls = Array[(Int, Int)]()
```